# IEnumerable repeats function

Tags: c#, linq

I have faced a strange problem. Here I reproduced the problem.

```
Random r = new Random();
List<int> x = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

var e = x.OrderBy(i => r.Next());
var list1 = e.ToList();
var list2 = e.ToList();

bool b = list1.SequenceEqual(list2);
Console.WriteLine(b); // prints false
```

Until now, I thought that Linq functions get executed when they are called. But, in this method it seems after I call `ToList` the Linq function `OrderBy` executes again. Why is that so?

Comment: See [Query Execution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738633(v=vs.100).aspx): "LINQ queries are always executed when the query variable is iterated over, not when the query variable is created. This is called deferred execution."

Comment: @Idle_Mind You should add that this is the documentation for *deferred execution.* Not every LINQ method executes at iteration time.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're looking at deferred execution. When you create a LINQ query it's basically a blueprint that says "when requested, perform these steps to manipulate the datasource". The tricky part here is that this request is only done by a distinct set of LINQ operations (`.ToList()` is one of these).

So when you call `e.ToList()` once it will randomize the data source because that's what the blueprint says it has to do. When you then call `.ToList()` again on this same blueprint, it starts again from the start and randomizes again.

A blueprint doesn't contain any state, it just says what should be done at each step of the way.

Comment: To be precise: LINQ uses deferred execution where possible. For `OrderBy` or `Where` it is only evaluated when requested (i.e. by the call to `ToList`). For others, such as `Count` or `Sum`, it is executed immediately.

Comment: @DanielRose Basically, wherever possible, LINQ will use deferred execution. For example, you can count or sum without iterating the entire collection anyway.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov you can't count or sum without iterating the entire collection; that's what you meant, right?