# Linq query with Entity Framework yields no result

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I am doing a query with linq and entity framework. The database I'm using is Oracle. Here is the code :

```
Entities bdd = contextWrapper.GetContext();

data = (from table in bdd.COP_PRDTICSOURES
        where (table.IDTTIC==ticketId && table.IDTPRD==productId)
        select table).AsEnumerable();
```

When I look at the variable `bdd.COP_PRDTIC_SOURES` using a debugger, it contains an entry matching my two criteria. However, after the execution of the query, the `data` variable contains no result.

Is there something wrong with my syntax ?

Some additional information:

- The entity i'm looking for isn't commited in the database when I perform this query. It's created before in the same transaction.
- I use a `foreach` on the data after, so it's not a problem of lazy loading.

Comment: this also may help. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32936340/4767498

Comment: What code accesses `data`, a `foreach`?

Comment: Linq uses lazy querying, this means that what you have in data isn't data but the query that will obtain the data. do if you then did another linq query it will just add the criteria to the query not retrieve data. that wont happen until you access the content of the query, by calling Enumerate this is done via foreach, ToArray, ToList, First, etc

Comment: @MikeT : I'm looking at data via the debugger, so it enumerates the enumerable, trigerring the query. I can see when I do this that the enumeration yields no result.

Comment: What database are you using? Is it possible that the query is case sensitive and that your criteria aren't? What are the results when you're omitting the 'Where' clause?

Comment: you are using entity framework to pass the query to a database to run there, the debugger doesn't have access to the database that may be the issue, so get the enumerate into the code, also just for FYI i've also found there is a context issue with LINQ where if you return a query without enumerating it then sometimes the garbage collector will destroy the items used in the query so that it wont run so you should enumerate the query before changing context ie leaving a method call

Comment: @BjörnBoxstart it seems to work when i remove the Where Clause. The debugger fails to get the data (but this time I get an error and not just empty collection), but the actual foreach that uses my variable works (and is very long, all the table is loaded, not only the one that was already in context)

Comment: And I'm using Oracle. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @BjörnBoxstart I used your idea, but instead of removing the where clause, I changed it to select an entry already present in database, and this time it worked. It seems that this method doesn't work on objects that are not dynamic proxies, or that are not already commited in the database, although I'm using the same transaction and context.

Comment: I think you should expand your question with the complete description of what you're trying to do. Only after asking more and more questions it appears that the actual problem is not that data is not retrieved from the database (because it ain't yet in the database).

Comment: Yeah I realized that this is a bigger problem. This is in a legacy project where transaction management is done in a custom way. The SaveChange method is called only at the end of the transaction, that is probably the problem. I assumed that since the object is in the context, it could be queried like any other object.

Answer (score 2):

`AsEnumerable` does not load data from DB. Calling it you are not executing the actual query, just changing how it is going to be executed in its entirety.

Use `ToArray` or `ToList` instead to load data explicitly. Or call `foreach` on this collection.

Comment: I do call foreach on the collection later (inside the same transaction). Beside, I think it's exactly what the debugger does when I look at the enumerable.

Comment: @Kaidjin when you just `watch` data  debugger does not show you data because it's not loaded. You must load data

Comment: @Backs actually, in Visual Studio, you can refresh the data of a variable in the debugger window and then it will do the same as when calling 'ToList()'.

Comment: @BjörnBoxstart yes, I know, I think it's equal to executing query and data loading. I just forget the name of this "button"

Comment: @Backs its an icon with two arrows at the right side of the 'value' field of a property in the debugging window. ;)

Comment: @BjörnBoxstart yes :) debugger displays text `Expanding the Results will enumerate the IEnumerable` - I'm talking about it